# Change asp:Label's Text using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>    

$("#btnGet").click(function () {
    $("#Label1").html("Michael");
}
```

This changes the Label's text into Michael on the browser.
Whereas clicking another button called Button1 causes the label's text gets empty.
How would it be possible to keep the value?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = Label1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Understanding how postbacks work is critical to developing a Web Forms application. As an alternative, update your page not to cause any postbacks, and do all server side interaction through [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) or [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: What's the easiest way to sort the case above?

Comment: Is ViewState enabled or disabled? Is your Page_Load or any other function in the page lifecycle resetting the value of the label without checking to see if it's a postback?

Comment: Enabled. Nothing resets the Label's value with or without checking isPostback.

Comment: Try using .val() as Amit suggested. Make sure the ID in your HTML (not the .aspx, but the generated HTML) is `Label1`. By default, if you use a master page or user control then the ID that you end up with on the client will be different from the ID you specified in in the .aspx file. To fix, you might set the `ClientIdMode="static"` on the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this -

```
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
    $("#<%=Label1.ClientID%>").html("Michael");
}
```

### EDITED

You have to set the label and as well as hidden-field to store the value and then access it in code behind, like this

```
<input type="hidden" id ="hdnName" runat="server" />

$("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $("#<%=Label1.ClientID%>").html("Michael");
        $("#<%=hdnName.ClientID%>").val("Michael");
    }
```

now retrieve it in code behind like this -

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = hdnName.value;
}
```

Comment: it IS posted posted back.

Comment: @Jude: you need to use `return false;` to prevent postback. Check my updated answer...

Comment: @Jude: Show me your **btnGet** code and also remove the `Text=""` from your label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61505/discussion-between-krishnraj-rana-and-jude).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $('[id$=Label1]').text("Michael");
});
```

`id$=` will match the elements that end with that text. ASP.NET auto-generates IDs like this.